# how to check animator state is finished unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

Below is my script, I want to check that animator state finished or not. If animator state(animation) is complete then do some action, but I am enable to do so,  Thanks in advance.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class fun_for_level_complet : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Animator animator_obj;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        check_end_state ();
    }

    public void level_complete()
    {
        if (this.GetComponent<movement_of_player> () != null) 
        {
            this.GetComponent<movement_of_player> ().enabled = false;
        }
        animator_obj.SetBool ("congo",true);

    }

    public void check_end_state ()
    {
        // here I want to check if animation ends then print
        // my state name is congo
        // animation name Waving
        // using base layer
        if (animator_obj.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName ("congo") && !animator_obj.IsInTransition (0)) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("anim_done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RiaanWalters That's Animation. OP is using Animator. They are both different.

Comment: @Programmer, Fair enough, I removed the flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out, and I done it by checking state starts or not if starts then check for end, by states names. Below is code, and working fine, remember(in last state you have to create empty state)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class fun_for_level_complet : MonoBehaviour 
{
public Animator animator_obj;
private string[] states = new string[]{ "congo" };
private string current_state_name = "";
private bool waiting_end_state = false;
private bool wait_for_anim_start = false;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (waiting_end_state) 
    {
        if (wait_for_anim_start) 
        {
            if (animator_obj.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName (current_state_name)) 
            {

                wait_for_anim_start = false;
            }
        } else 
        {

            check_end_state ();
        }
    }
}

public void level_complete()
{
    if (this.GetComponent<movement_of_player> () != null) 
    {
        this.GetComponent<movement_of_player> ().enabled = false;
    }
    animator_obj.SetBool ("congo",true);
    waiting_end_state = true;
    wait_for_anim_start = true;
    current_state_name = states [0];
}
public void check_end_state()
{

    if (!animator_obj.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName (current_state_name)) 
    {
        waiting_end_state = false;
        if( current_state_name==states[0] ) 
        {
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("inagmegui").SendMessage ("make_it_true");
            print ( "animation has been ended" );
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use events on animation clips. It's explained in Unity manual:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationEventsOnImportedClips.html

In **Animation Inport Settings** in **Annimations** tab You can find **Event** heading. Position the playback to the end and click **Add Event**. Fill the **Function** field with name of the function to call at the end of animation. Just make sure that Game Object with this animation has a corresponding function.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any transitions and would like to to be notified when the animation has ended for the "stateName" in layer 0, I did by calling the following IEnumerator :

```
public IEnumerator PlayAndWaitForAnim(Animator targetAnim, string stateName)
 {
     targetAnim.Play(stateName);

     //Wait until we enter the current state
     while (!targetAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(stateName))
     {
         yield return null;
     }

     //Now, Wait until the current state is done playing
     while ((targetAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime) % 1 < 0.99f)
     {
         yield return null;
     }

     //Done playing. Do something below!
     EndStepEvent();
 }
```

The main logic is once the state is entered, we should check if the fractional part of 'normalizedTime' variable reached 1, which means the animation has reached its end state.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom StateMachineBehaviour like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AttackBehaviour : StateMachineBehaviour
{
  public GameObject particle;
  public float radius;
  public float power;

  protected GameObject clone;

  override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
  {
    clone = Instantiate(particle, animator.rootPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    Rigidbody rb = clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.AddExplosionForce(power, animator.rootPosition, radius, 3.0f);
  }

  override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
  {
    Destroy(clone);
  }

  override public void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
  {
    Debug.Log("On Attack Update ");
  }

  override public void OnStateMove(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
  {
    Debug.Log("On Attack Move ");
  }

  override public void OnStateIK(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
  {
      Debug.Log("On Attack IK ");
  }
}
```

Documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html